# SQL counting query

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Sorry if this is a basic question.

Basically, I have a table that is as follows, below is a basic sample

```
store-ProdCode-result
13p      I10x    5
13p      I20x    7
13p      I30x    8
14a      K38z    23
17a      K38z    23
```

my data set has nearly 100,000 records.

What I'm trying to do is, **for every store find the top 10 prodCode.**

I am unsure of how to do this but what I tried was:

```
select s_code as store, prod_code,count (prod_code)
from top10_secondary
where prod_code is not null 
group by store,prod_code
order by count(prod_code) desc limit 10
```

this is giving me something completely different and i'm unsure on how I go about achieving my final result.

All help is appreciated.

Thanks

The expected output should be: for every store(s_code) display the top 10 prodcode

so:

```
store--prodcode--result
1a      abc       5
1a      abd       4 
2a      dgf       1
2a      ldk       6
```

.(10 times until next store code)

Comment: Expected output should be?

Comment: My gut is telling me to suggesting looking into the PIVOT function (depending on what version of SQL you are using) but as above, the expected output would be useful.

Comment: @juergend I have edited my post with the expected outcome

Comment: Let me know if anything doesn't make sense

Comment: Please don't deface your question once it has received answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for Window functions.

```
SELECT
    s_code,
    prod_code,
    prod_count
FROM
    (

        SELECT
            s_code,
            prod_code,
            prod_count,
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY s_code ORDER BY prod_Count DESC) as prod_rank
        FROM
            (SELECT s_code as store, prod_code, count(prod_Code) prod_count FROM table GROUP BY s_code, prod_code) t1
    ) t2
WHERE prod_rank <= 10
```

The inner most query gets the count of each product at the store. The second inner more query determines the rank for those products for each store based on that count. Then the outer most query limits the results based on that rank.
o

Comment: do I replace t1 and t2 with my table name? @JNevill

Comment: I ran and got the error:  ERROR: syntax error at or near "Table"

Comment: `table` needs to be replaced with your table name. `t1` and `t2` are merely aliases (names for those subqueries) you can change them to whatever you like.

Comment: it now says  ERROR: column "top10_secondary.s_code" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Yep. I forgot that part. I've update the answer accordingly.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390479/return-first-x-results-from-each-group-in-sql-query?rq=1   Try ROW_NUMBER vs RANK depending on what results are expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the table twice in the FROM clause, once for the data, and once to get a count of how many records have fewer results for that store.

```
SELECT a.s_code, a.prod_code, count(*)
  FROM top10_secondary a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN top10_secondary b
         ON a.s_code = b.s_code
        AND b.result < a.result
 GROUP BY a.s_code, a.prod_code
HAVING count(*) < 10
```

With this technique though, you may get more than 10 records per store if the 10th result value exists multiple times.  Because the limit rule is simply "include record as long as there are less than 10 records with result values than mine"

It looks like in your case, "result" is a ranking, so they would not be duplicated per store.

Comment: i get the following error:  ERROR: column b.result does not exist

Comment: I don't have the exact column names for your table.  Is the table called top10_secondary, and does it have a column called "result" ?   If it is something different like r_code, then you'll want to rename both places "result" is used on that line.

Comment: the table is called top10_secondary.. the result field is from the result of a count(prod_code) as result..
also get  ERROR: schema "b" does not exist

Comment: For this to work, you will need to first get the data into a format like your "basic example" data posted in the question, either with a sub query or make a new table.